# Service stops and starts with just the start command Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, systemd, services

I have recently created a service on my Ubuntu LTS server allowing me to test the uptime of my network. The script itself works as intended, but when I attempted to make it into a service I encountered some issues where the service stops itself (via the command stop) as soon as it starts.

Control File:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
start)
   /home/user/network_script/network_script.sh &
   echo $!>/var/run/network_script.pid
   ;;
stop)
   kill `cat /var/run/network_script.pid`
   rm /var/log/network_output.status
   rm /var/run/network_script.pid
   ;;
restart)
   $0 stop
   $0 start
   ;;
status)
   if [ -e /var/run/network_script.pid ]; then
      echo network_script.sh is running, pid=`cat /var/run/network_script.pid`
      echo /var/log/network_script.status
   else
      echo network_script.sh is NOT running
      exit 1
   fi
   ;;
*)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

System File:

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Script

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh start
ExecStop=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh stop
ExecRestart=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh restart
ExecStatus=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh status

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Output of status:

```
network_script.service - Network Script
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/network_script.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2023-01-03 14:07:46 EST; 8s ago
    Process: 25131 ExecStart=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh start (code=exited, status=0/S>
    Process: 25133 ExecStop=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUC>
   Main PID: 25131 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 9ms

Jan 03 14:07:46 greengoblin systemd[1]: Started Network Script.
Jan 03 14:07:46 greengoblin network_script_controls.sh[25136]: rm: cannot remove '/var/log/network_output.status>
Jan 03 14:07:46 greengoblin systemd[1]: network_script.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `Type=forking` to your `[Service]` section.,

From the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=):

> If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the main service process, and the service manager will consider the unit started when the parent process exits. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX services. If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can reliably identify the main process of the service. systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits.

In addition, it's good practice to let systemd know about your PID file, so it can determine if the process is still running or crashed:

The man page says this about `PIDFile=`:

> Takes a path referring to the PID file of the service. Usage of this option is recommended for services where Type= is set to forking. The path specified typically points to a file below /run/. If a relative path is specified it is hence prefixed with /run/. The service manager will read the PID of the main process of the service from this file after start-up of the service. The service manager will not write to the file configured here, although it will remove the file after the service has shut down if it still exists. The PID file does not need to be owned by a privileged user, but if it is owned by an unprivileged user additional safety restrictions are enforced: the file may not be a symlink to a file owned by a different user (neither directly nor indirectly), and the PID file must refer to a process already belonging to the service.
>
> Note that PID files should be avoided in modern projects. Use Type=notify or Type=simple where possible, which does not require use of PID files to determine the main process of a service and avoids needless forking.

This means your service should look like:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/network_script.pid
ExecStart=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh start
ExecStop=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh stop
ExecRestart=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh restart
ExecStatus=/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh status
```

---

That said, take a closer look at that last paragraph of `PIDFile=`.  Since you are using systemd, you don't need to track the PID yourself.  That makes your forking script unnecessary.  Systemd automates this for you.

I would ditch `/home/user/network_script/network_script_controls.sh` and have this unit file instead:

```
[Unit]
Description=Network Script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user/network_script/network_script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Thank you very much I have implemented all of this and it works like a charm! Sorry for the basic question, still getting used to Linux scripting!

Comment: You're very welcome.  It looks like you were learning from an old post which was written during the SysV/systemd crossover days.  Modern systemd simplifies a lot of the work that used to be necessary.